# how to link libraries in vcpkg to my library using cmake?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to use cmake and vcpkg to write a project in vs2019 recently.

I want to link the dynamic library in vcpkg to my own dynamic library, but I have encountered some troubles.

I hope someone can help me correct the mistake.

My project structure:

```
project
-engine
 -Engine.h
 -Engine.cpp
 -Window.h
 -Window.cpp
 -InstanceManager.h
 -InstanceManager.cpp
 -MouseListener.h
 -MouseListener.cpp
 -KeyboardListener.h
 -KeyboardListener.cpp
-main.cpp
-CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("mario")

include_directories("./engine")

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable (mario main.cpp)

add_library(engine SHARED
"engine/Engine.h" "engine/Engine.cpp" 
"engine/Window.h" "engine/Window.cpp"
"engine/InstanceManager.h" "engine/InstanceManager.cpp" 
"engine/MouseListener.h" "engine/MouseListener.cpp" 
"engine/KeyboardListener.h" "engine/KeyboardListener.cpp")

target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE glfw)

target_link_libraries(mario PRIVATE engine)
```

It shows C1083 cannot open include file “gl/glew.h”: No such file or directory.
However, when I write this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("mario")

include_directories("./engine")

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable (mario main.cpp
"engine/Engine.h" "engine/Engine.cpp" 
"engine/Window.h" "engine/Window.cpp"
"engine/InstanceManager.h" "engine/InstanceManager.cpp" 
"engine/MouseListener.h" "engine/MouseListener.cpp" 
"engine/KeyboardListener.h" "engine/KeyboardListener.cpp")

target_link_libraries(mario PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(mario PRIVATE glfw)
```

It works fine.

Is this a bug or I made mistakes?

Comment: this belongs on codereview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE glfw)
```

are wrong!

it should be:

```
target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC glfw)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("mario")

include_directories("./engine")

set(CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_library(engine SHARED
"engine/Engine.h" "engine/Engine.cpp" 
"engine/Window.h" "engine/Window.cpp"
"engine/InstanceManager.h" "engine/InstanceManager.cpp" 
"engine/MouseListener.h" "engine/MouseListener.cpp" 
"engine/KeyboardListener.h" "engine/KeyboardListener.cpp")
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE glfw)

add_executable (mario main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mario PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(mario PRIVATE glfw)
target_link_libraries(mario PRIVATE engine)
```

executable file should also link to libraries in vcpkg.

Comment: if your "public" headers in engine do include glew or glfw then you must make this dependency public i.e. `target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC GLEW::GLEW)` and if main is not including directly them don't directly target_link in mario to it but use the transitivity...